# How to join 2 pods in PODS 2 framework?

Tags: php, wordpress, podscms

How can I use fields from the second pod record based on the value from the relationship field in the first pod?

Let's say I have a pod called **countries** with fields **country_name** and **country_language**

In the second pod called **languages** I have fields **language_name** and **language_flag**

---

**country_language field is a relationship field dropdown with values from languages (language_name)**

What I want is to somehow be able to echo the **language_flag** field (corresponding to language_name of that row) when using this code:

```
<?php
     $params = array(
        'limit'   => -1
     );
     $countries = pods( 'countries', $params );

     if ( 0 < $countries->total() ) {
          while ( $countries->fetch() ) {
?>
     <h2><?php echo $countries->field( 'country_name' ); ?></h2>
     <br>
<?php
          } 
     } 
?>
```

I was thinking that something like this could work but of course it doesn't:

```
<h2><?php echo $countries->field( 'country_name' ); ?></h2>
<img src="<?php echo $countries->field( 'languages.language_flag' ); ?>">
<br>
```

I am uusing PODS 2 and trying to display the results in my theme's header.php.

Comment: For now I have solved it with an additional pod, that I have initialize, but I thing some better solution could exist.

Comment: Any explanaition of the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If language_flag is a file field, you might want to be using languages.language_flag.guid instead.

Pods 2.0 has a new function available too, which is $countries->display( 'field_name' ) so you could try checking that out too.